# Error in Foreign Key and one to one field relationship between two Apps In Django Project

Tags: foreign-keys, one-to-one

In my Django project i have two apps first app(product) and second app(store), product app has a custom user model while store app don't have custom user models. when i try to use a foreign key or one to one relationship between the apps after implementing the code like this for example

```
from product import models as product_models

class Chart (models.Model):
      #Other Fields Here
     user = models.ForeignKey(product_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and i also tried this method

```
from product.models import User

class Chart (models.Model):
      #Other Fields Here
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and also here is how my Database router looks like for allow_relationships

```
class StoreAppRouter:
      route_app_labels = ["product", "store"]

      #Other Codes And Functions Here 
     
     def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
       
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None
```

after implementing all this codes when i try to run makemigrations it runs and makemigrations successfully, but when i run ./manage.py migrate specifying the database alias `--database=store_db` instead of migrating successful it return an mysql error

```
   _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1824, "Failed to open the referenced table 'User'")
```

can someone please help me out in tackling this issue honestly i have been battling with this for the pass few days it really fustrating.